# Getting Bad Request by calling the WebClient post

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

Prepared a code:

I call a service, that actually works when I test it with Post Man (the ContantType="application/xml" there.. POST.

But:

--

```
val webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://mydomain/web/services/validation")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            .build();


    final WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec = webClient.post();

    MyResponseData myResponseData = requestBodyUriSpec

            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .acceptCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(MyResponseData.class)
            .block();
```

--

as result I always get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
```

in the logs, never get a `myResponseData`

// I use both jaxb and Jackson annotations, just to show that I tried it too.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyResult")

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "MyResult")
@AllArgsConstructor // TODO:
@Data
@Builder
public class MyResponseData {

    public MyResponseData() {}

    @XmlElement(name = "Members")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Members")
    private List<Member> memberData;

}
```

Any idea?

The MyResponseData maps to the xml.
I still have troubles to see the response in the log. It is another question.

The response XML is like:

```
<MyResult>
<Members>...</Members>
</MyResult>
```

No idea, what's wrong. And seems it is "popular" unanswered question on SO.

Comment: If you go to https://mydomain/web/services/validation via Postman (or curl it), what do you get back?

Comment: the `<MyResult>
<Members>...</Members>
</MyResult>`

Comment: Update after some time: I saw different type of issues with reactive webclient, "drop connection" / netty. Related to network configuration. So far I could not use this client for prod.